# uncrustify options for lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, uncrustify

My question is about Uncrustify 0.62 and lambdas. What uncrustify.cfg options can format code like this:

```
void f1b()
{
    std::for_each( a, b,
                   [ ] ( int& b ) -> foo
    {
       b += 3;
       return(beer);
    }
                 );

}
```

to code like this:

```
void f1b()
{
   std::for_each(a, b,
                 [] (int& b) -> foo
                 {
                    b += 3;
                    return(beer);
                 }
                 );
}
```

?

NB: Now next lines :

```
nl_cpp_lambda_leave_one_liners=false
nl_cpp_ldef_brace=add
sp_cpp_lambda_assign=add
```

are in uncrustify.cfg.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You might like this:

```
indent_paren_open_brace=true
```